# If statement and O(1) complexity

Tags: java, if-statement, complexity-theory

If there is an if else condition and if consists of 2 lines and else of 1 or generally the one has one more line, is the program O(1) ?

edit1: The following example is about linked lists.

For example:

```
    public String smth() throws NoSuchElementException{
        if (size!=0) {  
            Object n = tail.item;
            
            if (size!=1) {
                tail = tail.prev;
                tail.next = null;
                
            }
            else{       
                head.prev = null;       
                head = head.next;
                tail = tail.prev;
            
                
            }   
            
            this.size = this.size - 1;
            return n.toString();
        }else {
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        }
    }
```

edit2:

Thank you all for your suggestions. The toString()  is the default one; I didn't create (override) a one one.

Comment: Yes. Even if both the `if` and `else` had 10 lines, it would still be O(1). Constant factors don't matter.

Comment: big-O doesn't measure lines of code but growth rate. It's based on the size of the input - if you give it a bigger input, does it take more operations and if so how does size relate to the amount of operations. If you don't have any sort of input (as in, you're not doing any variable amount of processing where the variable amount is determined from outside the algorithm), then by definition it's an `O(1)` algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While both metrics tend to be correlated with overall performance (because programs that "do more things" will typically take longer to run), lines of code and computational complexity don't measure the same thing.

To clarify, to say that a program's complexity is `O(1)` simply means that it takes a constant number of steps regardless of the size of the input. Adding more lines of code will not, in and of itself, change the computational complexity (unless one of those lines is doing something that's more complex than `O(1)`).

Put another way, 30 `O(1)` operations, 50 `O(1)` operations, and 100 `O(1)` operations are all still `O(1)`. However, 99 `O(1)` operations and an `O(n)` operation is `O(n)`.

That being said: please do be sure to check the `n.toString()` line. I don't have a lot of insight as to what that actually contains, but it *might* be `O(n)` depending on how it's implemented. If that line is `O(n)`, it would make the entire method `O(n)`; otherwise, unless I'm missing something, I don't see anything there that would make this anything other than `O(1)`. (Also, I'll freely admit that I don't recall the computational complexity of throwing exceptions in Java, that's something that I'd have to do more research on).

Comment: I don't think there would be a problem with the exceptions as the exercise suggests that it should be O(1) and also throw an exception.

Answer (score 1):

`O(x)` refers to the following concept. But first, a tip: tip: You can't say "this algorithm is O(n^2)" without actually explaining what n is. It's rarely said because it tends to be obvious from context, but it is nevertheless a completely meaningless statement without locking down what the variable(s) used in the O(x) description represent. Even `O(1)` makes no sense unless you enumerate the 'variable(s)' (it doesn't have to be a literal parameter or variable in your method) it is O(1) for.

Make a line graph. On the x-axis, put 'n'. Whatever n might be (see tip above). Then, on the y-axis, put 'time taken by computer to calculate it'.

When you start out (with low n), these graphs tend to be *wildly* all over the place, because you're more measuring random chance, whether your winamp takes over the CPU core for a moment to decode some more mp3, etcetera. But, as long as you move far enough to the 'right' (high n value), the curve settles down and turns into something recognizable.

An O(1) algorithm will settle down into **a horizontal line** (because if you graph `y = 1`, it's a horizontal line). For example, let's say we look at the operation: "Retrieve the value associated with the key, in a `Map<Integer, String>`, using the `.get(k)` method". Clearly, the 'n' is therefore: The size of that map.

So let's do it! Let's make a simple bit of code that loops from 1 to 100 million, and per loop, it makes a new hashmap, puts that many keys in there, and then starts a stopwatch, and then runs a .get() operation, and then ends the stopwatch. Then we graph*.

For most map impls in java, the curve will end up looking like a horizontal line: The amount of time that `.get()` operation takes just isn't changing, whether the map has 5 entries, or 50 million of em.

For some, such as TreeMap, the curve settles down into a curve that looks like `y = log x`. Which is a line that slowly grows, but, very, very, very slowly, and as it grows, it slows down more and more.

That eventual 'settles down into' curve? *THAT* is what O(nlogn) means: That the curve eventually settles down into something that looks roughly like graphing the formula `y = x * log(x)`.

This is also why you never say some algorithm is `O(5*n^2 + n)` - because that curve, once you get past the beginning bits, looks just like `O(n^2)` does.

So, going back to your question: What could 'n' be about? If n is about 'size of linkedlist', well, your algorithm clearly does the same steps regardless of how large your linked list is. It's therefore O(1) relative to 'size of list'. Hypothetically (this is a bit bizarre, in that it has no relationship to the list implementation), but if you define 'n' as: "Number of fields the objects inside have", and your toString impl goes through all the fields to print them, then it WOULD be `O(n)`. This isn't a useful distinction (your list impl has nothing to do with the toString impl of the things it stores, so why are we confounding things by bringing that in?), but it goes to show that you can't answer what the performance characteristics of an algorithm are without first explaining which variable(s) you have.

You can have multiple; for example, in the operation of: "Given a regular expression as a string, and then an input string, how long does a Thompson/NFA algorithm take to match the input against the regexp?" The answer is generally given as "`O(n+m)` where n is the size of the regular expression and m is the size of the input string".

*) It really isn't that easy, you'd have to run a lot of get operations and get an average, there are frameworks like JMH to do this, though.